# What happens on using deprecated kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly?

Tags: ios, background-fetch

It seems kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly has been deprecated what happens on using it?

What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious alternative is to use `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly`.

> After the first unlock, the data remains accessible until the next
>   restart. This is recommended for items that need to be accessed by
>   background applications. Items with this attribute do not migrate to a
>   new device. Thus, after restoring from a backup of a different device,
>   these items will not be present.

However, I'd recommend reading the following from Apple - 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/item_attribute_keys_and_values - 
there's several options that might be more appropriate.